# Definition of an equivariant connection and equivariant curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, connections, equivariant

Can anyone give me a reference which precisely stated the definition of an equivariant connection and equivariant curvature?

Precisely, If G be a compact lie group acting linearly on a smooth manifold M, and assume that $E \longmapsto M$ is a rank $r$ vector bundle then what do I mean by an equivariant connection and equivariant curvature and how does one formulate these two objects in local coordinate?

I haven't found any good reference or paper where these are written explicitly. It would be very helpful if someone addresses me for the above.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by a group acting linearly on a manifold?

Comment: I am not sure, only guessing... I feel “equivariant connection” should be talked in the situation of “equivariant map”... I would be thinking there is action of $G$ on both $E$ and $M$ such that $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ is $G$-equivariant in the sense $\pi(g.p)=\pi(g).p$ for all $g\in G$ and $p\in E$?..

Comment: §7.1 of _Berline, Nicole; Getzler, Ezra; Vergne, Michèle_, Heat kernels and Dirac operators, Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften. 298. Berlin etc.: Springer-Verlag. vii, 369 p. (1992). [ZBL0744.58001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0744.58001).

Comment: @ Praphulla Koushik, yes it is correct that ``$\pi$ is equivariant''. I mean there is a natural action on E of G, which is the lift of the action of G on M.

Comment: Thanks  @ Francois Ziegler, I was reading Heat kernels and Dirac operators, but I found that the authors discussed equivariant superconnection (Def 7.3). Can you elaborate a little that the formula for equivariant superconnection $(A_g \alpha)(X) = (A-i(x))(\alpha(X))$ for $X$ in lie algebra, will it be same or not for my case. I think here the situation is a little simpler. I just want a notion of a connection on a vector bundle where the bundle gets an action by lift form the action on the Manifold and the connection should preserve the action.

Comment: you mentioned about action of G on M alone.. so, asked... I do not know about super connection.. Here is my guess... I am going to the set up of corresponding principal $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ bundle, $\pi:P \rightarrow M$.. The action of $G$ on $E$ induce an action of $G$ on $P$.. A connection on $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ is a $1$-from on $P$ satisfying some conditions... As there is an action of $G$ on $P$, it makes sense to ask this $1$-form to be compatible with this action of $G$, a $G$-invariant form.. In that case I call this a $G$-equivariant connection?? I don’t know.. @Anantadulalpaul